Routing via Express and onclick buttons is leading to non-application of CSS Stylesheets
I am making use of Node and Express for backend of a website along with EJS for frontend templating. While rerouting from one page to another I am facing into the same issue again and again.
I had only two routes for my site:

/home

/game/:foo


On clicking on a card(HTML article) for a specific game, it would take you to another webpage containing the information for that game, this information changes based on the parameterized URL. The thing is, whenever I try to go the path /game/:foo, it would not apply the styles at all. The styles for the /home path are being applied even though they are in the same directory as the one for the /game/:foo path.
I used logging statements to see what was happening and also went into the Networks tab of the Development Tools and saw that the stylesheets are being returned with a 404 error response. The browser console also printed an error stating that the "MIME type" of these stylesheets was being received as text/html and hence they could not be applied to the webpage.
The logging statement: console.log(`Game page for game: ${req.params.foo}`) also essentially confirmed this as the names of the stylesheets were also being returned for the request.
I then switched to making use of URL queries to reroute to a specific game path. I have not yet implemented it this yet but going to /game?game-name=foo must show me the correct page, whereas going to /game must only show me the layout and styles without the data.
Now here is the issue. I have added a click Event Listener to every card on the /home webpage and it essentially uses the following line of code to route to another page. window.location.href = "/game" .
When I implement this, on clicking one of the cards the page it reroutes to /game/ and shows the same "MIME type" errors which I was receiving earlier. When I manually remove the extra / in the URL, it routes correctly to the page **along with** the styles being applied. The onclick event is specifically routing to /game/ instead of /game . I am afraid that if I implement the queries, then the same problem will occur again.
Can anyone help me in solving this issue via using the first method for parameterized URLs or the second one using queries?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
